# Noises of switching power supply

Tags: noise-spectral-density

[image: The voltage +15V]
[image: Schematic]
I made a switching power supply (input: 24VDC, output: +-15Vdc) for LEM (current sensor). Noises of the power supply caused the output of LEM to become a bad waveform, but I don't know how to eliminate noises of switching power supply that show on the below picture.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Where was that measurement taken?

Comment: It looks like this whole design is solely because you wanted the LEM isolated. Why must it be isolated? The isolated analog regulator circuitry is well filtered, so it seems more likely it's magnetic coupling between the transformer or inductors and the LEM or later circuitry. How close are they to the LEM? Does re-orienting them change the noise? Does the switcher get its power from the same line you are measuring the current? How fast must the LEM output be? If it need only be slow, you could just filter out high frequencies.

Comment: @Colin, I believe that is the LEM output.

Comment: Another question: Does the input to the LEM have the same noise as the output?

Comment: the first picture shows the power supply of LEM, not LEM's output. The output of LEM includes many peaks which were create by the noises of power supply. And i want to eliminate the noises of power supply.

Comment: Did *you* make this design, is it a reference design, or a commercially made module? A lot of times seeing the actual layout can help to identify issues. Are there some low ESR capacitors scattered around that we're not seeing, or is it just large electrolytics? Is the primary driven with a 50kHz signal? Is there a specific reason for your diodes (D10-D13) to directly feed the chokes (L4,L5) instead of a capacitor?